# search for a value in json file with perl similar to query in DB

Tags: json, perl, parsing

I have a JSON file `JSON.dat` which contains thousands of entries like this

```
'{"apple":1,"banana":2,"cat":3,"dog":4,"elephant":5}'
```

I need to search for a fruit and get the corresponding ID, like a function search(cat) should return 3.
What is the best and efficient way to do this since its a JSON file with thousands of entries.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to load a module from CPAN, such as [JSON](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON), which can convert JSON into a hash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;
use feature qw( :all );

use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;

my $json = '{"apple":1,"banana":2,"cat":3,"dog":4,"elephant":5}';
my $ref  = decode_json( $json );

say Dumper $ref;
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a data serialisation standard and is used to convert data structures to and from a character string for transmission or storage. A JSON string shouldn't be used without converting it to a data structure native to the language you are using

Once you have converted your sample data to a hash reference, looking up, say, the `cat` element is a trivial hash access

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use JSON 'decode_json';

my $data = do {
    open my $fh, '<', 'JSON.dat' or die $!;
    local $/;
    decode_json <$fh>;
};

print $data->{cat}, "\n";
```

#### output

```
3
```